# Magento 2 - Using context variables for cache segmentation

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I am trying to deliver different content with magento 2 based on default country of the visitor.
I am using for that a plugin like this: https://github.com/dmytro-ch/m2-custom-cache-context/

But magento seems to ignore my customs context variables set with a plugin beforeGetVaryString.

I am using version 2.4.1

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanx